# I want to download the pdf like landscape format in my codeigniter application

Tags: codeigniter

I want to download the output file in landscape format using A5 or A6 sheet but it shows portrait format.

```
$this->load->library('Pdf');
$pdf = new Pdf('L', 'mm', 'A5', true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->SetTitle('Pdf Example');
$pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true);
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The screen are download in portrait format